# calling every class that inherits a base class without knowing the class exists c#

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I'm trying to implement a system in a websocket server similar to what unity3d does. they have a base class called MonoBehavior that all classes inherit from.

these class have certain functions (start, ongui, update) that get called at certain intervals.

every class that inherits from that class has its functions called (update is called every frame)

I want to make a base class and then call that and have every class that contains one of the functions automatically called like unity3d does. I've tried googling but have no idea what this type of behavior with classes is called to even get a useful result

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't be better of with having a list of all the objects of the sub classes?

Comment: yes I'm sure as I'm designing a framework and when used there will be an unknown amount of sub clases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just implement a static Manager class, like below:

```
public static class CallManager
{
    public static HashSet<Callable> callables = new HashSet<Callable>();

    // Other management code...
}
```

With a base class, that all your callable classes subclass, that automatically adds the each new instance to Set of  callable objects managed by your `CallManager`:

```
public abstract class Callable
{
    public Callable()
    {
        OnCreate();
    }

    protected void OnCreate()
    {
        CallManager.callables.Add(this);
    }

    public abstract void Start();
    public abstract void OnGUI();
    public abstract void Update();
}
```

Now, whenever someone creates a new `Callable`, the base `Callable` constructor will update the `CallManager` with the new `Callable`. A full example program is below:

```
class Caller
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Callee1 c1 = new Callee1();
        Callee2 c2 = new Callee2();
        foreach (Callable c in CallManager.callables)
        {
            c.Start();
            c.OnGUI();
            c.Update();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Callable
{
    public Callable()
    {
        OnCreate();
    }
    protected void OnCreate()
    {
        CallManager.callables.Add(this);
    }
    public abstract void Start();
    public abstract void OnGUI();
    public abstract void Update();
}

public static class CallManager
{
    public static HashSet<Callable> callables = new HashSet<Callable>();
}

public class Callee1 : Callable
{
    public Callee1()
    {

    }
    public override void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callee1::Start");
    }
    public override void OnGUI()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callee1::OnGUI");
    }
    public override void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callee1::Update");
    }
}

public class Callee2 : Callable
{
    public Callee2()
    {

    }
    public override void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callee2::Start");
    }
    public override void OnGUI()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callee2::OnGUI");
    }
    public override void Update()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Callee2::Update");
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do something like this without having to instantiate the subclasses via new() ? Like is there some way to search the namespace for any class that inherits from the base class and then call them ?

Comment: @JacquelineLoriault In order to create the objects, their constructors will have to be called. However, with the code above, the constructors need not be called by the framework. This framework will track new `Callable` objects, wherever they are initialised. As long at the object subclasses `Callable`, the `CallManager` will maintain a record of them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
public static class Caller {
    public static event EventHandler Updating;
    public static Update() {
        var handler = Updating;
        if (handler ¡= null) handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
 }

public abstract class Base {
    protected Base() {
        Caller.Updating += Caller_Updating;
    }
    void Caller_Updating(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Update();
    }
    protected abstract Update();
 }
```

For what i understand, you want that all derived class have the method called. This way when you call Caller.Update all derived class of Base have they Update method executed.

Comment: The derived classes will be called *if* they've added their own event handlers, which is not something you can enforce. Also, since the event is public, any unrelated third-party may also be listening to that event.

Comment: @dcastro Update will be called on ALL derived classes because the event is registered in the parametrless ctor that all derived classes must call. I have used in some scenario this pattern and no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to the [Template Method](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html) design pattern, also commonly known as *hooks*. It's the building block of many, many frameworks. It works something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public void Start()
    {
        //execute start logic
        DoThis();
        DoThat();

        //call base class's hook
        OnStart();
    }

    protected abstract void OnStart();
}
```

You declare an abstract method `OnStart` that derived classes must implement. When the base class's `Start` method is called, the base class invokes the *hook* which is then executed by the derived class.

If you want to make overriding the hook *optional*, then you declare the method virtual with an empty implementation, i.e. `protected virtual void OnStart() { }`.

It might be also worth mentioning that this is at the core of the [Hollywood Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle): *"Don't call us, we'll call you!"* (i.e., you don't call the framework's classes - the framework will call you!)

Comment: can you show some implementation example ? I get an error if I try to call new BaseClass()

Comment: @JacquelineLoriault That's because `BaseClass` is abstract. You have to create a concrete class that derives from `BaseClass`, and instantiate that concrete class. If you've never heard of abstract classes, you might want to take a look at these two documents: [Abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) and [Abstract and Sealed Classes and Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx).

Comment: @JacquelineLoriault you cannot instantiate an abstract base class.  Only derived classes.  You would create classes based on 'BaseClass' and then instance them.  Another approach is to use Interfaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx

Comment: @NebulaSleuth Interfaces don't really relate to this particular issue, and might just end up confusing him :/

Comment: then this will not do what I need. I already know about inheritance but this style would require a list of each subclass to go through and that's what I'm trying to avoid. not to mention in Unity 3D you don't use override you just use Start() or Awake() I'm wondering if its using some form of reflection

Comment: @JacquelineLoriault Why would you need a list of subclasses? That's not what happens at all. I'm very positive this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @dcastro maybe, maybe not.  You are right in that he asked specifically about inheritance, and I agree that Interfaces versus inheritance is a bit of a larger discussion and a bit off topic.  However, I suspect he doesn't have enough information to make an informed design decision and was trying to be helpful. :)